# Android SQLiteException

Tags: android

Here's my app, the AVD starts up but when I try to open the app I get a message

> "Your App has stopped working unfortunately"

This is my Logcat details:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEproducts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEproducts(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTproductnameTEXT);
```

Any help is more than appreciated.

Here is the Code:

```
public class MyDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "store.db";
public static final String  TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String  COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String  COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";


public MyDB(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory   factory, int version) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 String query = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
        COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "TEXT" +
                 ");";
 db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put space after `TABLE` like `"CREATE TABLE "` and also after every column name.

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
                 ");";
```

Comment: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "productnameTEXT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE products( _idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT productnameTEXT );

Comment: try the query I provided